# Display attribute of a foreign key in a form in Django

Tags: django

I have 2 models

```
class Task(models.Model):
    taskid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default = increment_booking_number)
    projectcode = models.ForeignKey('Project', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='projectid')
    taskname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    taskdescription = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

and

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default = increment_project_number)
    teamcode = models.ForeignKey('Teammember', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='teamcode', blank=True, null=True)
    projectname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    projectdescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

and in my form I want to display the projectname but it displays "Object object"

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = (
        'projectcode',
        'taskname',
        'taskdescription',)
```

I tried something like this: projectname = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Project.objects.all()) but it's not good...

Any advice please?

Comment: what is not good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default = increment_project_number)
    teamcode = models.ForeignKey('Teammember', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='teamcode', blank=True, null=True)
    projectname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    projectdescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.projectname
```

add **str** method to your model will fine.more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods)

Comment: This was the solution! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to add str() method at the end of your Task Model

```
 class Task(models.Model):
    taskid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default = increment_booking_number)
    projectcode = models.ForeignKey('Project', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='projectid')
    taskname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    taskdescription = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    #add this
    def __str__(self):
        return self.projectname
```

str() method allows us to  return a nice, human-readable representation of the model for more info refer to documentation of [str()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#s-str) method

**Note:**
you have to add this code above the Task Model Class in case you are using Python2:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Task(models.Model):
    taskid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default = increment_booking_number)
    projectcode = models.ForeignKey('Project', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='projectid')
    taskname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    taskdescription = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.projectname

    def __unicode__(self)
        return self.__str__()
```